# Java compiler will not enter my for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write an application which will populate an array with random numbers. Everything seems to work fine until I try to enter the for loop in my populateArray method.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PerformanceTester {

//takes an empty array, but the size must be allocated BEFORE passing 
//to this function. Function takes a pre-allocated array and input size.
public static int[] populateArray(int[] inputArray, int n) {

    //Create the number generator
    Random generator = new Random();

    int length = inputArray.length;
    System.out.println("Inputted array is length: " + length);

    for (int i = 0; i == length; i++) {
        // for debugging purposes: System.out.println("For loop entered.");
        int random = generator.nextInt((2 * n) / 3);
        // for debugging purposes: System.out.println("Adding " + random + " to the array at index " + i);
        inputArray[i] = random;

    }
    return inputArray;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] input;
    input = new int[10];
    int[] outputArray = populateArray(input, 10);
    System.out.print(outputArray[0]);

}
}
```

As shown by my output, the compiler clearly enters the method (when called on line 29) but seems to stop all execution when the for loop is reached. I'm 100% sure that my loop has proper initialization and termination operators, because length is equal to ten.

I'm honestly stumped, but like most cases, I'm certain its a very simple answer. My output is below:

```
Inputted array is length: 10
0 //The array is not populated with numbers, so all indexes of the array return zero.
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely you meant your loop test to be this right?

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

Otherwise, `i == length` will never be true (unless `length == 0`) and it will never enter the loop.

You also could have used:

```
for (int i = 0; i != length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write `i<=length` rather than `i==length` in the termination condition...because first it initiate the variable `i` as `0` and then check the termination condition (`i==length` as in your case), only if it becomes true it would enter in the loop.

Comment: `<=` to length will result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write "i < length" as the condition of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition is not what you want. i < length is what you probably want.

Also it has nothing to do with the java compiler.